# Pass specific data from array to model

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array of locations that when a users clicks on that card it should show a modal with that specific locations data

How do I pass the data to the modal?

```
 <!-- Card -->
  <div class="locationCard" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" >
   <div class="locationText">
      <?php echo $slide['title']; ?>
   </div>
   <?php echo '<img class="cardImage" >' . wp_get_attachment_image( $slide['image'], $size = 'medium',["class" => "cardImage","alt"=>"some"]) . '</img>'; ?>
</div>

 <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><?php echo $slide['title']; ?></h5>
         </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```